# add xml closing tags explicitely using c#

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, openxml

Here is my problem, I am working with openxml word sdk with c#.
I have structure something like this.

```
<w:p>
<w:r>
<w:r>
<wordcontent>
<wordcontent>
<w:r><w:r>
</w:p>
```

above is simple xml.
what I want to do is on specific condition "wordContent" is replaced
by some other content.

If such condition matches. I want to close top  tag explicitely before the wordcontent
and start another one to make it look something like this.

```
 <w:p>
    <w:r>
    <w:r>
</w:p>(add this)
    <wordcontent>
    <wordcontent>
   <w:p> (add this)
    <w:r><w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain in detail about the ?

If it is standard openxml element we can use classes to construct xml and replace it.

Finding and replacing text in xml string is not feasible. Because the structure of open xml element occasionally changes, like first attribute becomes second and vice versa.

Hope this helps!